# Why should I use goog.ui.Checkbox instead of a regular input?

Tags: javascript, input, rendering, semantics, google-closure

Google closure offers a custom checkbox component which seems to create an overhead to render a simple checkbox. Why is it worth using it?

I'm using the Google closure framework heavily and I was wondering if using those input replacement components makes sense.

The answer can be extended to explain also if a *text* input should be replaced also with a goog.ui.Textarea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came to the answer myself: both are good depending on their use. All these custom inputs of google closure have something in common: they extend `goog.ui.Control`. This component is pretty useful for handling states: `disabled`, `hover`, `active` and `focused`. This means the following thing:

1. If you're just creating a **form for a new database record**, it makes little sense to use these components. It's an overkill. A simple input which receives the data can even be sent by post (a `goog.ui.Control` isn't able to do this by itself).
2. If you're creating a dynamic web interface which handles **events** and/or **states**, it's far better to use a `goog.ui.Control` given it already handles these events and it's capable of some default event and state-change handling with it's ascendants/descendants.

The only exception here is if you have a mix of `goog.ui.Control`s with form inputs and you want an unified user experience. In which case you have to play with style-sheets or sacrifice complexity/maintenance for either of them.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to. But sometimes you may want to use it, since goog.ui.CheckBox has tree states: CHECKED, UNCHECKED, UNDETERMINED, while a plain checkbox has only two states.